# How to assert that an exception has not been raised?

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, exception, visual-studio-2013

I am using the unit testing features in Visual Studio 2013 for my application.

I am trying to write a test for a class whereby you pass in a specific object to the constructor, and depending on the state of the object passed, an exception may be thrown.

I have written stubs for each object state, and have written test cases for the scenarios where the constructor will throw an exception as follows:

```
TEST_METHOD(constructor_ExceptionRaised)
{
    // arrange
    const InvalidStub stub;

    // act
    auto act = [stub] { const Foo foo(stub); };

    // assert
    Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::ExpectException
        <MyException>(act);
}
```

How should I approach a scenario where I want to pass a valid stub and simply assert that no exception was raised?  I want to be purely concerned with a specific `MyException` not being thrown (rather than any exception).

I have hacked together a test method as follows but not sure if there is a simply "1 line" approach that would fit my needs:

```
TEST_METHOD(constructor_NoException)
{
    // arrange
    const ValidStub stub;

    try
    {
        // act
        const Foo foo(stub);
    }

    // assert
    catch (MyException e)
    {
        Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::Fail();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::Fail();
    }
}
```

I am not confident I need to also fail "any exception" being raised, as this should(?) be picked up by the test runner (i.e. fail the test).  Along the same reasoning, would the following essentially be the same test:

```
TEST_METHOD(constructor_NoException)
{
    // arrange
    const ValidStub stub;

    // act
    const Foo foo(stub);

    // assert
    // no exception
}
```

Comment: Of the two `catch` blocks, one is necessarily redundant (since they do the same). Anyway, one possible alternative is to return an indicator of what happened, from the `act` function. The use the testing framework's relevant means of checking the return value.

Comment: I don't know anything about Visual Studio's unit testing framework, but most unit testing frameworks will fail the test if an exception propagates out of the test method.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - If the function returns void, is it valid to assert that the function pointer is a void pointer?

Comment: @immibis - Yes, this is true so by this basis would my final test example be sufficient to test that no exception was raised?

Comment: @rasteve: What exactly do you mean by "assert that the function pointer is a void pointer"? A function pointer is never a `void*`.

Comment: What would be the effect of passing in this object in the constructor? Assert on that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - I mean, how can I assert that the return of a function is void?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - The effect will be that the `foo` object is an instance of `Foo`.  In Visual Studio's unit test there is a `AreSame` function but you need to create an expected and an actual object of the same type.  There is no `IsInstanceOf` function.

Comment: That last test you showed is all you need to prove that passing a valid stub to the `foo` constructor doesn't cause an exception; if you really wanted to be pedantic about it, you could add `Assert.IsTrue(true)` (or however you say that in C++!) since if any exception occurs that statement will not be executed anyway and the test will fail at the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following test method to show that a constructor doesn't throw an exception:

```
TEST_METHOD(constructor_NoException)
{
    // arrange
    const ValidStub stub;

    // act
    const Foo foo(stub);

    // assert
    Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::IsTrue(true);
}
```

When an exception is raised the test automatically fails.  The exception details are given in the failure message.

When no exception is raised the test will pass as I am asserting `true == true`.